# How to add an element in a dictionary in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, dictionary

I am learning JS and I am stuck at a point. Basically I have a dictionary and I want to update that dictionary whenever a button is clicked and the user enters some data in prompt. Some how I can't update the dictionary.

```
    "use strict";



let views = {View1:"From localStorage"};

let btn = document.getElementById("myBtn")
btn.addEventListener("click",function(){
    let vname = prompt("What is the name of the new view?")
    views[vname] = vname + " 77"

})





let views_ser = JSON.stringify(views)
localStorage.setItem("views",views_ser);

let views_deser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("views"))

for (let keys in views_deser){

    document.write(keys + "<br>")
    document.write(views_deser[keys]+ "<br>")
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You seem to be adding it just fine. What leads you to suspect that you aren't? Also, stay away from `document.write()` - it's archaic and has almost no use in modern JavaScript. Use DOM manipulation methods instead.

Comment: Well When I am using document.write() I can't get all the key value pairs. I only get View1 and From loclaStorage,

Answer (score 0):

This is *not an answer* - you already got it right yourself! - but something to illustrate the use of SO snippets. To concentrate on the "adding something to a dictionary" here is a demo of the first part of your code:

```js
let views = {View1:"From localStorage"};

let btn = document.getElementById("myBtn")
btn.addEventListener("click",function(){
let vname = prompt("What is the name of the new view?")
views[vname] = vname + " 77"
console.log(views); // show current state of "views" dictionary
})
```

```html
<button id="myBtn">add view</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
"use strict";

const views = {View1:"Original entry"};

const btn = document.getElementById("myBtn")
btn.addEventListener("click",function(){
    let vname = prompt("What is the name of the new view?")
    views[vname] = vname + " 77"
    updateOutput("list");
})

const updateOutput = (outputContainerID) => {

 const output = document.getElementById(outputContainerID)
 if(!output){
  return;
 }
 
 let outputHTML = '';
 
 Object.keys(views).forEach( key => {
      outputHTML += `<li>${key}: ${views[key]}</li>`;
 });
 
 output.innerHTML = outputHTML;

}

updateOutput("list");
```

```html
<button id="myBtn">Add</button>

<hr>

<ul id="list"></ul>
```

You need to update the output every time you add an item. To do this, move the "output stuff" into a function so you can call it every time an item is added (and once at the beginning, too).

For the example, since `localStorage` does not work well in sandboxes, I changed it to just keep your storage in a variable. But it would work the same way with `localStorage`.